# Validation with ManyToOne

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I have an Entity "Element" with a ManyToOne relationship with List (a list can have multiple elements)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Liste")
 */
private $list;
```

How can I validate a form to add a new element, with just passing the id of the list and not the list itself ? (The list has to exist)

Answer (score 5):

in the old days (pre 2.8) we were able to set the `cascade_validation` flag which would then validate any child objects pre-persist.  This was at best hit and miss.

That gone, the correct way is to do the following (note the `valid` constraint):

[from the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

```
use use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class stuff 
{
    // ....

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Liste")
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $list;

    // ....
}
```

this will force the framework the call any validators that you have on the related entity.

**this is available from symfony 2.7**

Answer (score 0):

You must add the form field with entity type like this:

```
->add('list', EntityType::class, [
        'choice_label' => 'my test title'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow by this steps:

1) Assign/Set entity class in Form

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'CoreBundle\Form\Type\YourEntity',
    ])
}
```

2) Create custom validation on YourEntity

```
@Assert\CheckExistingList()

class YourEntity
{
  public function __construct()
}
```

3) Create new validator file CheckExistingListValidator.php and write your validation logic inside below function.

```
public function validate(Constraint $constraint)
{
    // logic here.
}
```

So whenever your Form will submit then this validation should be called and error message show in Form error list.